# Netbeans imported JAR not loading on run

Tags: java, netbeans, classpath, netbeans-7

i see this question has been posted many times but it has been solved with adding 
`-Djava.library.path="./path"` to the VM runtime options.

I have to build an app in JAVA which uses the JNotify classes.

this is the sample code:

```
package test;

import net.contentobjects.jnotify.JNotify;
import net.contentobjects.jnotify.JNotifyListener;

/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
public class Test {

    public void jnotifydemo() throws Exception {
    // path to watch
    String path = System.getProperty("user.home");

    // watch mask, specify events you care about,
    // or JNotify.FILE_ANY for all events.
    int mask = JNotify.FILE_CREATED
        | JNotify.FILE_DELETED
        | JNotify.FILE_MODIFIED
        | JNotify.FILE_RENAMED;

    // watch subtree?
    boolean watchSubtree = true;

    // add actual watch
    int watchID = JNotify.addWatch(path, mask, watchSubtree, new Listener());

    // sleep a little, the application will exit if you
    // don't (watching is asynchronous), depending on your
    // application, this may not be required
    Thread.sleep(1000000);

    // to remove watch the watch
    boolean res = JNotify.removeWatch(watchID);
    if (!res) {
        // invalid watch ID specified.
    }
    }

    class Listener implements JNotifyListener {

    public void fileRenamed(int wd, String rootPath, String oldName,
        String newName) {
        print("renamed " + rootPath + " : " + oldName + " -> " + newName);
    }

    public void fileModified(int wd, String rootPath, String name) {
        print("modified " + rootPath + " : " + name);
    }

    public void fileDeleted(int wd, String rootPath, String name) {
        print("deleted " + rootPath + " : " + name);
    }

    public void fileCreated(int wd, String rootPath, String name) {
        print("created " + rootPath + " : " + name);
    }

    void print(String msg) {
        System.err.println(msg);
    }
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Hello World");
    new Test().jnotifydemo();
    }
}
```

When i run this i get:

```
Error loading library, java.library.path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32;(continues)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jnotify in java.library.path
```

I have setup a Netbeans project and added the JAR file to the project so that the JAR is correctly in the lib/ folder of my project and everything is set in NETBEANS.

This correctly works if is setup the `-Djava.library.path="./path"` argument of the java VM, but if i imported my lib in NETBEANS that should be included in the path automatically.

I am doing something wrong or it is necessary to put every .jar in the classpath system variable? I would like to release this app so it can run on other systems that does not have JNotify in their libs.

Thanks

I am using Netbeans 7.2 on Win 7 32Bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are messing java jar files as library which has to be added only in netbeans classpath:

Simply in NetBeans on project properties click and adjust Library having your JAR file.

[image: Project Properties]

For the native libraries (so,dll,...) you need to have set: -Djava.library.path. As you did in your question.

So you have 2 steps:
1. from http://sourceforge.net/projects/jnotify/files/jnotify/jnotify-0.94/jnotify-lib-0.94.zip/download add jnotify-0.94.jar to your libraries as in picture above (this will update your classpath automatically)
2. jnotify.dll, or jnotify_64bit.dll for 64-bit windows place is some directory and ad this to your -Djava.library.path - add this to VM option of the projects property

Comment: okay, i added the JAR already to the Libraries, but the clue is that strangely it does not work. It looks compiling fine, but the error is present when i try to run it

Comment: Additionally, when i try to run the VM with  **java -classpath "lib/jnotify-0.94.jar" -jar jntest.jar** it gives me the same error: Error loading library...

Comment: You need to add dll - native library to -Djava.library.path="./path_to_dll" in order to link DLL to your JVM